# history.back in backbone seems don't work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying use windows.history.back() but nothing happens. Exactly when the event call history.back appear for a few second or less only the menu of the previous page.

Below the view where the function is called:

```
               var LandscapeView = Backbone.View.extend({

   template: Handlebars.compile(template),

 events: {

  },

  initialize: function() {
      this.geolocation();
      $(window).on('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);



  },



/*    render: function() {
      //var context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));//eliminare
      //var context=this.model;
      var html =this.template();

      this.$el.html(html);

       $('#pagina').empty();
       $('#pagina').append(this.$el.html(html));


      return this;
    },*/




    geolocation:function(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win);
    function win(pos){
        console.log("gps");
       /* var el='<div>'+ pos.coords.latitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.coords.longitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.timestamp+'</div>';
        $('#pagina').html(el);*/



    var lat=pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon=pos.coords.longitude;

    var options={

        center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

      var html=$('#pagina');
      console.log(html);
    var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('pagina'),options);        
          console.log(map);  

    };





    },



    onOrientationChange: function() {

if(window.orientation === 0) {
   window.history.back();

       }
    }












 });

 return LandscapeView;

  });
```

and here the view previous that history.back can't re-call:

```
          var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: Handlebars.compile(template),

 events: {
  "click .log_out":"log_out",
  "click .prove":"prove",

  },

  initialize: function() {

      console.log("inhomeview");

     this.render();

    $(window).on('orientationchange', this.onOrientationChange);



  },



    render: function() {
      //var context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));//eliminare
      var context=this.model;
      var html =this.template(context);
      console.log(html);
      this.$el.html(html);




       $('#pagina').empty();
       $('#pagina').append(this.$el.html(html));


      return this;
    },


    onOrientationChange: function() {

if(window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90) {
   new LandscapeView();

        }
    },












    log_out:function(){
        console.log("logout");
        Parse.User.logOut();
     //   new AppView;//ERRORE UNDEFINED NOT A FUNCTION
     window.location='index.html'  ;//METTERE UNA NEW APPVIEW MA DA ERRORE!!!
    },

    prove:function(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win);
    function win(pos){
        console.log("gps");
       /* var el='<div>'+ pos.coords.latitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.coords.longitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.timestamp+'</div>';
        $('#pagina').html(el);*/



    var lat=pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon=pos.coords.longitude;

    var options={

        center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
        zoom:15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

      var html=$('#pagina');
      console.log(html);
    var map= new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('pagina'),options);        
          console.log(map);  

    };





    }


 });

 return HomeView;

   });
```

and this is my router:

```
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "user/:objectId":"prova",
        "settings":"settings",//mettere id dell utente loggato
        "friends":"friends",
        "mailbox":"mailbox"
    },




    home: function() {

           console.log("inrouter");       
           new AppView();           
    },


 settings: function(){
     console.log("settings");
     var view=new SettingsView();
     $('#pagina').html(view.render().el);
   },

friends: function(){
     console.log("friends");
     var view=new FriendsView();
     $('#pagina').html(view.render().el);
   }   ,

mailbox: function(){
console.log("mailbox");


   }   






});

return AppRouter;

});
```

and here the main where the history starts:

```
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", run, false);
     run();

    function run() {

        var sync = Backbone.sync;
 Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
 options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'qS0KLMx5h9lFLG**yhM9EEPiTS3VMk');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'nh3eoUo9G**vbF2gMhcKJIfIt1Gm');
  };



sync(method, model, options);

},

        app = new AppRouter();
        Backbone.history.start();

        Parse.$ = jQuery;


     Parse.initialize("qS0KLMx5h9l****tyhM9EEPiTS3VMk",
               "H4m*****aGOBqlWzRDW8IrPDpF9qLN7Duy");

    }
```

Comment: could extend the code with your router definition?

Comment: have you started backbone history after you set up the router?

Comment: i've added main.js in the code section above, where history starts

Comment: You should produce a [short self-contained example](http://sscce.org).